# zend framework 2 не отoбражаются breadcrumbs

Tags: php, zend-framework-2

Есть следующая фабрика:

```
class ProfileNavigation extends DefaultNavigationFactory {

    protected function getPages(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {

        if (null === $this->pages) {
            /* @var $mvcEvent MvcEvent */
            $mvcEvent = $serviceLocator->get('Application')->getMvcEvent();

            $router = $mvcEvent->getRouter();
            $routeMatch = $mvcEvent->getRouteMatch();
            $params = $routeMatch->getParams();
            if (array_key_exists('nickname', $params)) {
                $navigation = $this->getProfilePages($params['nickname']);

                $pages = $this->getPagesFromConfig($navigation);

                $this->pages = $this->injectComponents(
                    $pages,
                    $routeMatch,
                    $router
                );
            }
        }
        return $this->pages;
    }

    protected function getProfilePages($userName) {
        return [
            [
                'label' => 'Added',
                'route' => 'profile/added',
                'params' => [
                    'nickname' => $userName,
                ],
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'Starred',
                'route' => 'profile/starred',
                'params' => [
                    'nickname' => $userName,
                ],
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'Collections',
                //'uri' => '/profile/' . $userName . '/collections',
                'route' => 'profile/collections',
                'params' => [
                    'nickname' => $userName,
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}

class ProfileNavigationFactory implements FactoryInterface {
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
        $navigation = new ProfileNavigation();
        return $navigation->createService($serviceLocator);
    }
}
```

В конфиге:

```
'profile_navigation' => 'Application\Navigation\Service\ProfileNavigationFactory',
```

Меню выводится нормально:

```
echo $this->navigation('profile_navigation')
                ->menu();
```

А вот breadcrumbs не выводит ничего:

```
echo $this->navigation()
        ->breadcrumbs('profile_navigation')
```

Может кто сталкивался, в чем ошибка, как решается? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю, Вам необходимо создать темплейт для отображения хлебных крошек и выводить следующим образом.

```
echo $this->navigation()->breadcrumbs('profile_navigation')-setPartial('layout/breadcrumbs.phtml');
```

Так как у хелпера `navigation->menu` есть стандартный метод отображения меню, оно у Вас отображается, у хлебных крошек такого метода нет, и необходимо использовать метод `setPartial`, или же расширять класс.